Can't log in Google online accounts
I'm running a clean installation of U24.04. If I try to connect a Google online account, the Sign in page does never launch.
I have tried with Firefox, Chromium and Chrome as default browsers with no success.
I checked the error console and found:
error creating account: no such secret collection at path: /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login
Any tip? Thanks!

It is better to go the developer console and see what error code do you get?

thanks! I have edited the post with the error

Is it only with Google specifically or with other clients as well?

And can you please re-edit your question by running nix-shell -p nix-info --run "nix-info -m" and pasting the result.

Google, Microsoft... anyone that requires to launch a log in web page

I guess my Nix installation is not properly configured yet, as the output for nix-shell -p nix-info --run "nix-info -m" is error:
error: file 'nixpkgs' was not found in the Nix search path (add it using $NIX_PATH or -I)

Good seems you are able to figure out the problem with your installation. Hope it could solve the related problem as well. Good luck!

Comments are not the place to put info that belongs in the question. Comments are where someone trying to help asks you for more info, you add the info as an edit to the question. Not everyone reads all the comments and they can and do go away in time.

Well, this seems to be a well known issue, and has already been discussed on many forums. It looks like your email client is not started because some of the message publishing is disabled by default. You need to be enable all of them for proper functioning of the email clients. You can read more in detail here but as a summary what you can do is enable G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all for the gnome-keyring-daemon .

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I've just had this issue after performing a "Clean up" on a fresh install of Debian 12 sid.
As it turns out I ran:
sudo apt purge --autoremove evolution

Because I want to use Geary
After that, that's when I was seeing the "No such secret" message.
Simply re-installing Evolution, then removing it with:
sudo apt remove evolution

fixed the issue.
